# OCaml - Read csv file into array

Tags: arrays, csv, ocaml

I'm trying to import a csv file in OCaml into an array. I do realise it's not the best fit for the langage and I'm not actually sure an array is the best structure, but anyway...
It's working fine, but I'm really uneasy about the way I did it.

```
let import file_name separator =
  let reg_separator = Str.regexp separator in
  let value_array = Array.make_matrix 1600 12 0. in
  let i = ref 0 in
  try
    let ic = open_in file_name in
    (* Skip the first line, columns headers *)
    let _ = input_line ic in
    try
      while true; do
        (* Create a list of values from a line *)
        let line_list = Str.split reg_separator (input_line ic) in
        for j = 0 to ((List.length line_list) - 1) do
          value_array.(!i).(j) <- float_of_string (List.nth line_list j)
        done;
        i := !i + 1
      done;
      value_array
    with 
      | End_of_file -> close_in ic; value_array
    with
      | e -> raise e;;
```

Basically, I read the file line by line, and I split each line along the separator. The problem is that this returns a list and thus the complexity of the following line is really dreadfull.
`value_array.(!i).(j) <- float_of_string (List.nth line_list j)`

Is there any way to do it in a better way short of recoding the whole split thing by myself?

PS : I haven't coded in Ocaml in a long time, so I'm quite unsure about the try things and the way I return the array.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OCaml `>=4.00.0`, you can use the List.iteri function.

```
List.iteri
  (fun j elem -> value_array.(!i).(j) <- float_of_string elem)
  line_list
```

You can replace your for-loop with this code and it should work nicely (of course, you need to keep the `;`).

On older version of OCaml, you can use List.iter with a reference you manually increment or, in a cleaner way, declare your own iteri.

Note that your code is not very safe, notably with respect to your file's size (in terms of number of lines and columns, for example). Maybe you should put your dimension parameters as function arguments for a bit of flexibility.

EDIT: for future readers, you can use the very simple [ocaml-csv](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv) (through OPAM: `opam install csv`)

Comment: Yeah, I know about the parameters, but it's just a one-off (well, 2) use, so it doesn't really matter. Will do it for good practice anyway, thanks a lot.